# How do I prevent Music app from using 1 GB of cellular data in less than 10 minutes?

Tags: ios, cellular-data, iphone, music.app, itunes-radio

I received 3 text messages within 10 minutes from my cellular carrier as I was driving in my car with iTunes Radio streaming music.

1. 10:20 pm - 65% of my 1 GB plan is used.
2. 10:22 pm - 90% used.
3. 10:28 pm - 100% used and a $20 fee for going over. The music got jumbled up at this point. It would play a split second, pause, and repeat.

[image]
[full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKIaL.png)

I went into Settings > Celluar to find the culprit. It was indeed caused by the Music app, so I immediately switched off its cellular usage. It had used up 1 GB in 10 minutes. This was the first time I attempted music streaming while driving.

In [all the articles](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2014/02/how-much-mobile-data-does-itunes-radio-use/) that I've read, they say iTunes Radio should only use 28 MB per hour - much less than what I just experienced. So what caused my meteoritic rise in data usage?

[image]
[full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39MDG.png)

The following screenshot shows that I have no local music collection, so the phone couldn't have been synching any music from the cloud. That infamous free U2 album that was uploaded to everyone's phone is not on my phone.

[image]
[full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJtv7.png)

More info:

- Background app refresh is turned off.
- iOS 8.1.1
- iPhone 6
- Music settings: "Genius" off. "Show All Music" off.

Comment: I noticed that the text messages said it's a shared data plan. Is it possible that another user on your AT&T plan was also using data, making the problem worse?

Comment: It could not have been someone else in my shared data plan, because the GB of usage appeared under my own Settings app.

Comment: It's always best to make sure you're updated to the latest version of iOS.

Comment: So it’s not really accurate to say your phone used 1GB in 10 minutes as prior to using the phone there was no indication that you had 100% remaining. What we do know is that you used 350MB between 10:20 and 10:28. Now it’s not impossible that there are also delays in your network provider sending these texts. And my own research and experience would say that it’s more like 2MB a minute however with higher quality audio it could be more. Still not enough to explain the usage, where I am going with this is you are unlikely to get an exact answer.

Comment: I notice you are on a pretty old version of iOS. I would suggest checking for updates and reinstalling if you continue to see this issue. But there’s no real way to see what happened and it may not be an issue again in future.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in iOS 8; it was fixed in later versions of iOS.

I encountered it personally whilst I was working at Apple and so did others: https://twitter.com/BenedictEvans/status/519966240484622336

More information: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4351602

Even doing everything to prevent it: https://www.imore.com/apple-music-eating-your-iphones-cellular-data-plan-heres-how-fix-it the problem still occurred.